# Appending information to multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm learning basic Linux commands and I came across something about appending date to multiple files at once. The question was:

"Translate from upper case to lower case, the first 20 lines of `filex`. Append the sorted output to `file10` and append all errors to file `error_log`."
The command it says to put into the command line is:

```
$ head -20 filex | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort >> file10 >>> error_log
```

I don't understand why it has `3 >>>` when "appending all errors to file error_log" as `>` means to overwrite and `>>` means to append, is this an addition to appending data or should it be `2 >` instead of `3 >`.
Please help

Comment: It was supposed to be there but I made a mistake on the command, I corrected it @DmitriChubarov

Answer (score 1):

The following answers the title of your question, not the body of it:

Use [`tee`](http://man.cx/tee) to append some text to multiple files:

```
{ date; echo "hello world"; } | tee -a file1 file2 file3
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no usage as `>>>` in command line. it gives `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`>' ` error.

Proper usage is

```
$head -20 filex 2>> error_log | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort >> file10
```

`2>>` will redirect all the std errors to the error_log file. You can use `2>>` after the command where you want to collect the error_log.

```
0 - for std input
1 - for std output
2 - for std error.
```

`2>&1 and 1>&2` these commands will redirect both the std out and stderr to the specified file.

Comment: Where is it supposed to get the content for `error_log` from?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the last redirection operator takes precedence, in `sort >> file10 >> error_log` it is `file10` that will not be appended.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: Fair enough. But that's even worse for this case.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 'head -20 filex | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort >> file10 | '____' >> error_log' can we use some thing like this

Comment: And that still doesn't do what the asker wants.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Please check now, i have updated answer.